# Div not centered in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to center a div and it works in  Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox. The     div is socIcon which will show linked social media icons. This div is below the full background image using css3.

```
 html {
 height: 100%;
 background: url(images/logoLandingPage.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 background-size:cover; 
 }

 #socIcon {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position:absolute;
 padding: 10px 0px; 
 bottom:0px;
 width:100%;



 /* Firefox */
 display:-mox-box;
 -moz-box-pack:center;
 -moz-box-align:center;


  /* Safari and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

  /* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center
  }
```

Comment: can you post the html??

Comment: Please try to make a fiddle out of your code and post the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align:center;
```

might help, but i am not sure , if you post the html i can make sure it work!

```
#socIcon {
     margin: 0 auto;
     position:absolute;
     padding: 10px 0px; 
     bottom:0px;
     width:100%;
    text-align:center;
      }
```